# Issues with Improvement Requests on Documentation

Tags: support, documentation

Why is there a limit of "improvement requests" on a particular topic/example. Especially in these early hours, there are tons of changes that need to be made. I understand how too many flags could become overwhelming, but it seems better to place all the changes there so that users can pick and choose the ones that they are best equipped to handle.

When a user "dismisses" an improvement request, does it disappear for all users or only for that particular user? Should there be a way of "answering" an improvement request that you feel is unnecessary, so that the request can be removed if the community deems the change unnecessary?